# How can I get a piece of a string between two specific characters from a string in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a Json file which I converted to a dictionary in python. 
One of the values called (target) in the dictionary has this string. I want to  create a file with this string name (dawn_tables_tornado_affected.txt) and writing the contents from another value of the same dictionary

```
target = /inc/ab_sdfs_sf/dawn_tables_tornado_affected.sql

with open("/Users/David/House/“ + str(point.get('target')) + “.txt , "w") as f:
    f.write()
```

How can I get the variable to only  use ’dawn_tables_tornado_affected’ ?

Comment: Show us your data and expected output.

Comment: What you posted isn't valid Python, is that your actual code?

Comment: @Cole, this is just few  lines from the code. Basically I want to get 'dawn_tables_tornado_affected' from the string. I tried the strip method with no luck. also used regex but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

There's some errors in your code

target should be a string and then wrapped in double quotes `"`

The character `“` isn't valid for string closing and should be replaced by `"`

If you want to extract `"dawn_tables_tornado_affected"` from `"/inc/ab_sdfs_sf/dawn_tables_tornado_affected.sql"` you can use the following :

```
target = "/inc/ab_sdfs_sf/dawn_tables_tornado_affected.sql"

file_name = target.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
```

`target.split('/')` will split the string into an array using `'/'` as delimiter. `target.split('/')[-1]` gets the last item of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this !

**Python code :**

```
import re
target = "/inc/ab_sdfs_sf/dawn_tables_tornado_affected.sql"
matchObj = re.match( r'.*/([^/]*)[.]', target, re.M|re.I)
print ("File Name : ", matchObj.group(1))
```

**Output :**

```
File Name :  dawn_tables_tornado_affected
```

**Verify through regex 101 :**

[image]